# Telerik DataSource, paging and filtering

Tags: filter, paging, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid.  The initial DataSource that is bound to the grid has 145 records.  I have filering turned on in the grid as well as paging and my pagesize is 20.  When I filter down to 75 records, the MasterTableView.Items collection of the grid shows 20 records.  This matches what's in the grid being displayed.  However, I need to perform a Mass Change on the data and need the 75 filtered records.  Is there somewhere in the Grid that has the 75 filtered records?  I want to avoid having to get all 145 records again and then manually filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik doesn't provide a server side API to access filtered data in the grid, but there are a working around provided on their forum.

The solution is to save filtered rows primary key while grid loading and then use IDs later to get your data.

```
bool flag = false;
    protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.FilterCommandName)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }

     protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (flag)
            {
                foreach (GridDataItem grdItem in RadGrid1.Items)
                {
                    int iID = Convert.ToInt32(grdItem.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString());
                    .  .   .   .
                }
                flag = false;
            }
        }
```

for more information check the following link on telerik site:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/how-to-get-filter-data.aspx